# CEN/XFS. How to specify the com port address for a specific device

Tags: c#, cen-xfs, ncr

I am working on the CEN-XFS standard. I set the configs from the documentation.

[image: Service providers]

[image: Logical services]

The documentation does not show setting the com port address for a particular device.

How to specify device COM port address for CEN-XFS SPI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be specified in the documentation of your service provider vendor. Usually it is set automatically when installing a service provider.